# NET Core API - referencing DLL which connects to different web services returns 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-core

I have .Net Core 2.1 REST API application. In it I reference dll file which connects to different web services, based on parameters. Each call returns exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()
```

The call works if it's invoked from regular .NET Framework application.
My API compiles without any issues. I went through some trouble getting it this far - first I had exception about missing System.Web.Services dll, later on I had to install NuGet System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, and now I have this exception. Any ideas how to make it work? Possibly without interfering in DLL code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confusing the different between .NET Core and .NET Framework. The System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager and System.Web.Services belong to .NET Framework and ONLY run on Windows OS and can't be used with .NET Core. Also, two libraries are used by WCF services which isn't exist in .NET Core.

Read here for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

Comment: I know the difference between them, all I wanted is to use .Net Framework library in .Net Core. My application is deployed on Windows Server anyway.

Comment: In fact, it can't be because they have different CLRs. And WCF is just considered for porting to .NET Core in a long roadmap. In case you still want to connect SOAP WS, I am afraid of you should use .NET Framework. Or you can use ASP .NET Web API 2 to connect your SOAP WS and then make another .NET Core API to call them, it is just temporary solution, not the best.